# JAXRSUtils No message body writer has been found Issue with SpringBoot 3 & Apache CXF 4.0.0 & JDK17

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

When we migrated from SpringBoot 2 to 3 & JDK to 17 and Upgrading Apache CXF Version from 3.4.10 to 4.0.0, we started getting "No message body writer has been found for class" when trying to send custom Object as JSON Response. Tried including @Produces Annotation and Included Jackson Library as well in dependency. In jaxrs.classes-scan-packages included org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider. But still its not able to convert the Response object into JSON. If i manually convert the Response Object to JSON using Object Mapper String and passing String as Response, its working fine. And also, its working fine for String and primitive data types response. Getting error only for custom objects.

Tried Following Steps

1. Included JSONProvider package in jaxrs.classes-scan-packages which results in same error
2. Tried downgrading apache-cxf version which results in same error
3. Tried with Fasterxml Jackson as well as Codehaus Jackson - Getting same error
4. Included Jettison dependency - Results in same error.

Sample Classes:
POM.xml - Minimum Dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>JAXRS-POC</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>JAXRS-POC</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cxf.version>4.0.0</cxf.version>
  </properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

***Model Class:***

```
 @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Response{
    private String data;
    private int statusCode;
    private String message;
    }
```

***Controller Class***

```
 @Path("/test")
    @Component
    @Produces("application/json")
    public class TestController{
    @POST
    @Path("/testupload/v1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Response upload(final MultipartBody body){
    
    try{
     Response response = new Response();
     response.setData("Test Data");
     response.setStatusCode(200);
     response.setMessage("Uploaded");
     return response;
      }
    catch(Exception e){
    //Error Handling
    }
}
```

***Application.yml file***

```
  cxf:
  path: /api
  servlet:
    init:
      service-list-path: /info
  jaxrs:
    component-scan: true
    classes-scan-packages: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
```

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example, ie part of the class file that does not serialise, part of the controller method that returns the custom class, the custom class definition and enough pom/gradle to simulate.

Comment: @JohnWilliams added required class files.

Answer (score 0):

Use jakarta version jackson, in CXF 4.0, the javax.*  packages are migrated to jakarta .*

Need to use jakarta version jackson, i debug the source code and saw that:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>        
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider</artifactId>       
    </dependency>
```